# Apache Rewrite Trailing Slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to use the following:

```
Redirect 301 /example/cookies http://test.butterscotch.co.uk/cookies?ref=test
```

Which ends up redirect to:

```
http://test.butterscotch.co.uk/cookies?ref=testexample/cookies
```

However if I do:

```
Redirect 301 /example/cookies/ http://test.butterscotch.co.uk/cookies?ref=test
```

And I try the URL:

```
http://oldhost.com/example/cookies/ (with the trailing slash)
```

it redirects to the new url correctly.

I need to be able to use the Redirect so it doesn't have to have the trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's causing your first issue, but the `Redirect` directive is probably not what you want when you're working with a query string in the redirect target. The `Redirect directive kind of links two URL paths together, so if I have a rule like:

```
Redirect /abc /xyz
```

and I go to `/abc/`, I'll obviously get redirected to `/xyz/`, and if I go to `/abc/def/g` I'll get redirected to `/xyz/def/g`. When I have a query string in the mix:

```
Redirect /abc /xyz?i=123
```

and I go to `/abc/def/g`, I'll end up getting redirected to `/xyz?i123/def/g`, which obviously isn't what I want.

Try using `RedirectMatch` instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /example/cookies/?$ http://test.butterscotch.co.uk/cookies?ref=test
```

or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example/cookies/?$ http://test.butterscotch.co.uk/cookies?ref=test [L,QSA,R=301]
```